# Django URLconf error

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am a beginner to django and I am studying from here.

http://www.madewithtea.com/simple-todo-api-with-django-and-oauth2.html

I got this error when I run.

[image]

This is my project structure and code for url routing. Although I know this is common error, I don't have clue for that.

[image]

How shall I solve that one?

Comment: You are requesting the root URL (`/`), but you have not configured a view for it. Either add the view (and add the `^$` url pattern), or visit a valid URL such as http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no URL for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in your url conf. You'll need to define a URL for that page by doing something like this:

```
url(r'^$', name.of.the.view),
```